# Django SSL Redirect snippet modification, not working as expected

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

I'm using Nginx as webserver, with a reverse proxy to a gunicorn django server.

I tried using the SSLRedirect snippet from here:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/

Because this snippet would always return false from `is_secure()` with my setup, resulting in a redirect loop, I had to make some changes.

SSL works, but when I access `http://domain.net/main` it doesn't redirect to `https://domain.net/main`. Isn't it supposed to do that?

Below outlines the modification I made:

```
if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL' in request.META:
    return True
```

And in my nginx conf (I only need SSL, http not required):

```
server {
listen 8888;
server_name domain.net;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /path/to/domain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/domain.key;

# serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
location /media/ {
    root /path/to/root;
}

location /static/ {
    root /path/to/root;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8881/;

    # note this line
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it entirely with nginx. No need to involve Django at all:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    # The rest of your original server config here
}
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, as im using only one port (not 443) that listens to 8888. And port 80 is being used by something else

Comment: Then, what's the problem? If you can't connect on port 80, then there's no need to redirect anything. Users have no choice but HTTPS already.

Comment: yes, but when the user connects through HTTP on the same port, a bad request error pops up. I want to redirect users connection to http on port 8888 to redirect to the https.

Comment: Then change `listen 80;` to `listen 8888;`

Comment: yeah then it would result in an infinite redirect loop

Comment: Not if HTTPS is bound to 443. Regardless, you've got enough there to work with. Just tweak it until it works with your particular setup, but the basic principle is sound.

Comment: well then it seems it's impossible to do so through the web server, since I 443 and 80 is being used by something else for me...